# Getting unknown symbol in Mac OS when translating language in VueJs

Tags: javascript, macos, vue.js, ubuntu-18.04, gettext

I'm using **get text plugin** for language translation in VueJs, although it's working totally fine with all browsers on linux-ubuntu OS but when I open the same with any browser with MacOS then it's giving me unknown symbol as given below in screenshots.

Image on chrome for ubuntu

[image: Image on chrome for ubuntu)]

Image on safari on MacOS

[image: Image on safari on MacOS]

**Note** - This is not a problem with any browser, as I've checked with both safari and chrome on MacOs, In both of them I'm facing same issue.

I don't known whether it's a problem with my approach, Operating system or I've missed something, I have provided the code below.

**app.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import GetTextPlugin from 'vue-gettext'
import translationsNL from '../translations/nl.json';
import translationsEN from '../translations/en.json';
import translationsDE from '../translations/de.json';
import VTooltip from 'v-tooltip'

Vue.use(VTooltip);
Vue.use(GetTextPlugin, {
    translations: {
        nl: translationsNL,
        en: translationsEN,
        de: translationsDE,
    },
    defaultLanguage: 'de'
});
window.Bus = new Vue();
Vue.config.productionTip = false;
```

some translations from **translations/de.json**

```
{
  "request_completed": "Einen Moment bitten, die Artikel werden in Ihren Warenkorb gelegt",
  "example_line": "Sie wechseln gerade zwischen Innen- und Außenbeleuchtung. Alle getroffenen Entscheidungen gehen verloren. Möchten Sie die Beleuchtungsart noch ändern? "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an encoding issue. Set it to `utf-8` in your `head` element in HTML.

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Comment: Hello @Ahmad Alfy, I've added the meta data but then also, not working